# Migrate Mixins to React 16 ES6

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, mixins, migrate

I am migrate my project from react 14 to react 16. I have many custom mixins. I know that the mixins are deprecated in react 16. The question is how to migrate the custom mixins ?

My Custom Mixin:

```
import Avatar from 'material-ui/Avatar';
import { apiConstants } from '../constants/AppConstants';

export default {
  avatar: (src, name, size) => {
    if (src) {
      src = src.indexOf('http') >= 0 ? src : `${apiConstants.API_HOST}/imgprovider?i=${src}`;
      return (
        <Avatar
          size={size}
          src={src} />
      );
    }

    if (name) {
      return (
        <Avatar
          size={size}
          backgroundColor="#306398">
          {name[0].toUpperCase()}
        </Avatar>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

and my new classe for Component in react 16 with ES6:

```
class Header extends React.PureComponent{

  mixins: [AvatarProfile] ?????  (HERE IS THE DOUBT)

  render() { }
}
```

How to do this?

Comment: I don't want to write this as an answer because people will probably try to kill me but ... I guess you can always install old react version and you can use something like `import React from 'react-14'`.

Comment: Read carefully https://reactjs.org/blog/2016/07/13/mixins-considered-harmful.html and then consider of switching pattern if you migrate to react 16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options for you to choose.

As I see it from your code, you don't really need a mixin here, your `avatar` does not use `this` from the base class, you can define it as a Component

```
export default function MyAvatar({ src, name, size }) {
    if (src) {
        src = src.indexOf('http') >= 0 ? src : `${apiConstants.API_HOST}/imgprovider?i=${src}`;
        return (<Avatar size={size} src={src}/>);
    }

    if (name) {
        return (<Avatar size={size} backgroundColor="#306398">{name[0].toUpperCase()}</Avatar>)
    }

    return null;
}
```

And later, instead of `this.avatar(src, size, name)` use `<MyAvatar src={src} size={size} name={name} />`

If you really need something like mixin, than you can define it like this:

```
export default function withAvatarProfile(superclass) {
    return class extends superclass {
        avatar(src, name, size) {
            return "avatar";
        }
    }
}
```

And use it later:

```
class Header extends withAvatarProfile(React.PureComponent) {
  render() { }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to know. Thank you so much!

Comment: I need your help one more time. When I import the new fuctcion Avatar I got this error: "TypeError: (0 , _mixinsAvatarProfile.withAvatarProfile) is not a function". This is my command:  import { withAvatarProfile } from 'AvatarProfile';

Comment: Could you add some code to show how you define it and use (codepen/jsfiddle...)?